# For the memory allocation in class constructors, is it safe to use initializer list for simplifying the expression?

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, default-constructor

What is the correct syntax to do that? And what should I pay attention when practicing such technique.

Comment: Post some code that illustrates what you are asking about.

Comment: You can do that safely yes.

Comment: Not much effort in this question...

Answer (score 0):

> ... correct syntax to do that?

```
 class Foo {
     Bar* bar_;
 public:
     Foo() : bar_(new Bar()) {}
 };
```

> And what should I pay attention when practicing such technique.

You should ensure to call `delete` appropriately

```
      ~Foo() { delete bar_; }
```

---

The better way though is to use a smart pointer:

```
 class Foo {
     std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar_;
 public:
     Foo() : bar_(std::make_unique<Bar>()) {}
 };
```

Comment: I was trying to use dynamic memory to modify my practice example, but I got lost because I am not quite sure about the correct syntax. And it become more confusing when I try to combine it with inheritance.